# how to format time in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, haml

i have problem with time format. Here is my controller. It is return all records for 2016-06-02.

```
def get_date_list
        @result = OpenStruct.new
        if params[:city_id]
            @result.day = Timetable.where(:tday=>"2016-06-02")
        else
            pust "no value"
        end
        render :json=>@result.as_json['table']
    end
```

and in my view i have javascript tag

```
:javascript
    var updateDate = function(){
        var city_id = $("#select_other_month").val();
        $.post("/api/get_district_list.json",
        {
            city_id: city_id
        },
        function(data,status){
            if (data.day){
                $("#bla").html("");
                $("#irts tbody").empty();
                console.log("status");
                var row = $("<tr>");
                for(i=0;i<data.day.length;i++){
                var row = $("<tr>");
                    row.append($("<td>"+data.day[i].id+"</td>"))
                .append($("<td>"+data.day[i].arrivedtime+"</td>"))
                .append($("<td>"+data.day[i].leavetime+"</td></td>"))
                .append($("<td>"+data.day[i].status_id+"</td></td>"))
                .append($("<td>"+data.day[i].total_time+"</td></td>"))
                .append($("<td>****</td>"));
                $("#irts tbody").append(row);
                }
                }
            console.log(data);

        });
    }
```

But it's displayed time like 2000-01-01T08:30:00.000+08:00. How can i format this to like HH:MM:SS.

Comment: `var d = new Date(); var h = d.getHours();
            var m = d.getMinutes();
            var s = d.getSeconds(); var customDate = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;`

Comment: It's printed system's current time. I just want print my string "2000-01-01T08:30:00.000+08:00" like hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to first convert it to a Date javascript object, which you can then use to create a timestamp which has the hh:mm:ss area which we can then splice out. The following code demonstrates this:

```
var date = new Date(data); // Create the javascript date object
var dateStamp = date.toTimeString(); // Create the base dateStamp
var dateText = dateStamp.split(' ')[0]); // Splice out only the part that we want
console.log(dateText); // 16:30:00
```

Comment: it's printed invalid on console